# How fix the winform app that having issues when they using in two separate system using same server

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have winform app that works fine but the problem is my client has two computers and both computers are connected one server computer to locally so I have add my access database to serve drive so both computers can access the file but the problem is when someone working both computer my winform only creating one input line in the data base for both users.

I don't know how to fix this issue. is there is anyway to write code that database can check the auto increment id filed which is using and create new id number for second user.

NO

I expect that when both computers in use who ever start app first get one ID number generated in the access database and the second user get next number from above number.

Comment: You are still going to have potential issues if you are not seeing it already, the database must be shared where other users can access it at the same time. You also should have a users table to keep track of users etc...

Comment: Make the ID column in the Access Database AutoIncrement...